# How can I add rows using repeatsection in angular formly instead of the add button?

Tags: angularjs, angular-formly

I want to show a form as a table in which the repeating tr's will be based on the data in JSON (response from the API). Currently formly allows repeat sections using add button but How to do the same using JSON data.

http://angular-formly.com/#/example/advanced/repeating-section

Answer (score 0):

Just add your data as next item in your model value of formly-form. 
Based on example if we will have such model

```
vm.model = {
    investments: [
      {
        investmentName:'abc',
        investmentDate:(new Date()).toDateString(),
        stockIdentifier:'',
        investmentValue:'',
        relationshipName:'',
        complianceApprover:'',
        requestorComment:''
      },
      {
        investmentName:'haf',
        investmentDate:(new Date()).toDateString(),
        stockIdentifier:'',
        investmentValue:'',
        relationshipName:'',
        complianceApprover:'',
        requestorComment:''
      }
    ]
  };
```

then when you will recive you're data (i assume you're using promises) in then section of the promise add recived data to vm.model.investments array
for example

```
someService.getMyData().then(function (data) {
    vm.model.investments.push(data);
}
```